# Hudson and e-mail notification

Tags: email, hudson, jenkins

Can I overwrite Hudson settings 'System Admin E-mail Address' for each job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some reading in the source at http://sorcerer.jenkins-ci.org/, and `hudson.tasks.MailSender` does not seem to consider anything but the globally configured admin email address when creating a mail.

So: No.

Or: An excellent reason to write your own notification plugin. :-)