# how to get a notification mail when build is killed/stopped/aborted

Tags: jenkins

How to configure Jenkins to send a notification email when a build is aborted or killed?
how can I configure Jenkins to send me a email notification in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email notification from Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884050/send-email-notification-from-jenkins)

Answer (score 2):

This feature does not come with Email Notification (Jenkins Mailer Plugin) , you need to use Email Ext plugin , After installation GO to advance settings and add 
Trigger "Aborted" to receive email in case the jenkins job is aborted.

[Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)