# Mail from Jenkins to gitlab user who broke the build

Tags: email, jenkins, gitlab

I studied : [Send email notification from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884050/send-email-notification-from-jenkins)

and my notification email in general is working.

But: can anybody tell me how I add just the person who broke the build to the mail-to field?

Build is usually started via gitlab push, people can log on to Jenkins using their gitlab account. I am somehow not able to figure out how to send a notification only to the person who started the build via push. That said, I am no dev-ops I am only learning by doing currently. Every example I find in the web is using a "hardcoded" email-address. That's not what I want. Thanks in advance! Additional information: there are two sorts of builds that I want to send emails from: some with pipeline scripts and the "normal" ones. In the "normal ones" you have mail sending in the Post-build-Actions, but as said, I would like to put a variable value to the recipient field. Like "The one who broke the build" How do I get this?
"Extended e-mail notification" does for an unclear reason not offer the possibility of smtp-login to mail server to me, only ssl, tls and OAuth 2, so I cannot use it.
The git plugin does also not seem to offer something I can use, or I just do not understand how it works.